# Android: Keep Second Screen on

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've built a little Test Application. The goal was:

- showing different content on a second screen
- keeping the second screen on at all times (as long the service runs)

Showing different content was easy using `DISPLAY_SERVICE` and the `WindowManager` (`WINDOW_SERVICE`).

Then I created a `ForegroundService` to do my work in the background, this included showing the content on the second screen.

Everything works as expected at this point.

But I want the second screen to be on all the time. Currently, when
I press the power button on the phone, the second screen goes black too.

I tried `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

### Update

Here is MyService:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.app.Presentation
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.PowerManager
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock
import android.view.Display
import android.view.WindowManager
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat


class MyService : Service() {
    private var wakeLock: WakeLock? = null
    private var presentation: MyPresentation? = null;

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        val powerManager = getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp::MyWakeLockTag")
        wakeLock?.acquire(10*60*1000L /*10 minutes*/)
    }

    private fun start() {
        var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "running_channel")
            .setContentTitle("Running")
            .setContentTitle("Hello:")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build()

        val dm = applicationContext.getSystemService(DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
        val dispArray = dm.displays
        if (dispArray.size > 1) {
            presentation = MyPresentation(this, dispArray[1])
            presentation?.window!!.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
            presentation?.show()
        }

        startForeground(42, notification)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        when(intent?.action) {
            Actions.START.toString() -> start()
            Actions.STOP.toString() -> stopSelf()
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        presentation?.hide();
        if (wakeLock?.isHeld == true) {
            wakeLock?.release();
        }
    }

    enum class Actions {
        START, STOP
    }
}

class MyPresentation(outerContext: Context?, display: Display?) :
    Presentation(outerContext, display) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check more about `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK` flag

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager

Comment: Thanks but. This constant was deprecated in API level 17. Most applications should use WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON instead of this type of wake lock, as it will be correctly managed by the platform as the user moves between applications and doesn't require a special permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I want the second screen to be on all the time. Currently, when I press the power button on the phone, the second screen goes black too.

This is the expected behaviour: the power button changes the state of the device regardless of the flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` for the main display too. In fact you can start with a blank activity from an android studio project, add the flag exactly as in the snippet here: https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/scheduling/wakelock
and verify that the main screen goes off when the power button is pressed. You can then put a low time (15 seconds) on settings->display->screen timeout (menu sequence for android 14) and verify that: screen goes black after 15 seconds, and when the app with the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON is displayed the screen timeout is inhibited and the screen stays on.

If you want to prevent the user to switch off the screen through the press of the power button, this was asked here: [Android - Is it possible to prevent screen from turning off programatically if user presses power button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70243666/android-is-it-possible-to-prevent-screen-from-turning-off-programatically-if-u) and it seems it's not possible, you could prevent the lock to be activated though using [android - how do i dismiss the lock screen on new android version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730610/android-how-do-i-dismiss-the-lock-screen-on-new-android-version)

If you want to keep the screen on and inhibit the timeout instead, note that (from previous link).

> Keep the screen on
> Certain apps need to keep the screen turned on, such as games or movie apps. The best way to do this is to use the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON in your activity (and only in an activity, never in a service or other app component).

The class you use, it's Presentation, and:

```
public class Presentation
extends Dialog

java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.app.Dialog
       ↳    android.app.Presentation
```

It's not inheriting from an Activity, so the flag is applied incorrectly and it will never work.

Edit:
You can launch an activity instead of a Presentation on the second screen, and so you can set the flag on the create method of the activity. Quite trivially, you can launch an activity on the second screen like this:

```kotlin
val exampleIntent = Intent(this, ExampleActivity::class.java)
exampleIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(
    exampleIntent, 
    ActivityOptions.makeBasic().setLaunchDisplayId(secondDisplayId).toBundle() 
)
```

In conclusion:

> keeping the second screen on at all times (as long the service runs)

This, considering that switching the screen off through the power button is not preventable, cannot be achieved on a not custom Android version.